# Credits: Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction

Tags: php, facebook-credits

I am using the PHP example given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/build/) and its giving the error given in URL. I did add the company details and testing in Sandbox Mode

Comment: same issue for all the samples

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130010/912623